# UITableViewCell delete animation with transparency

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a gradient as the background of my app. I added a table view on top, which has a clear background. The cells don't have a background and the headers have a translucent background (white, 20% alpha).

I am using `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to create expandable/collapsible containers. The problem is that, because I have transparency, when I the user taps to hide the cell, the `UITableViewRowAnimationTop` goes over the section headers and only disappears once the animation is complete, which is very confusing.

How can I solve this? Is there a way to create a custom `UITableViewRowAnimation`

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem yet?

Comment: Yes, I found a workaround using a different implementation, because the problem as presented here cannot be solved. If you want more details let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround which is based on setting the `alpha` value to zero (animated) while the cell deletion is being animated. With this approach the deleted cell is fading out while being overlapped by the next cell.

Basically you need a reference to the exact cell you want to delete at the specific time. Then you just call:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
    cell.alpha = 0.0
})
```

Don't forget to reset your `alpha` property to `1.0` since the view will likely be reused. I'm doing this in my custom `UITableViewCell` cell subclass:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    // Reset alpha because we're setting it to zero on cell removal        
    alpha = 1.0
}
```